# How to change the Screen coordinates to bottom left corner

Tags: qt, qt-quick

By default, y-axis in a Qt Window is increasing from top to bottom. How can i convert it from bottom to top of the window. I have seen a solution in Qt Widget application, but how can we do it in a QML project.Here QWindow is the root of the application.

In OpenGL, the y axis is increasing from bottom to top, but in Qt it is in reverse style. Why it is like that ?

Regards
Ansif

Answer (score 1):

Qt has zero at the top because that's the way Window, OSX, Linux etc all define screen coordinates for 2D graphics.

OpenGL is more often used for 3D graphics, which usually defines the direction of up (y axis) as being positive, as it's easier to imagine 3D space this way with respect to objects and their positions.

Other than convention, there's no real reason for one way or the other. In fact, in 3D the y axis doesn't necessarily have to be oriented to up and down, though it usually is.

To switch directions on the screen, to place zero at the bottom and have an increasing y axis up the screen, subtract each coordinate from the full screen height.

Comment: Hi Merlin,Thank you for this nice solution. But is there any physical properties that we can modify in Qt to change the coordinates.

Comment: Do you mean globally as a one off setting? I don't think there is, unless someone else knows otherwise. If you build Qt yourself, you could add one.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have used your early solution. Thank you.

Comment: In order to get the y position in terms of bottom left, you would have to subtract the QML Item's y position AND height from the screen position.